# Set LaTex export fallback font

Tags: latex, fonts

How do I set a fallback font for LaTex export to pdf?

I have the following setting in my `init.el`.

```el
(setq org-latex-classes
      '(("article"
         "
\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\\usepackage[heading]{CJK}
\\usepackage{zhnumber} % package for Chinese formatting of date time (use /zhtoday)
%\\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime} % set date time to numeric

% Set default indentation

\\setlength\\parindent{12pt}

% Set Paper Size, Page Layout (another variable is 'bindingoffset')
\\usepackage[margin = 1.5in, paper = a4paper, inner = 2.5cm,
outer = 2.5cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}

% Keep paragraph indentation while having a line break in between paragraphs.
\\edef\\restoreparindent{\\parindent=\\the\\parindent\\relax}
\\usepackage{parskip}
\\restoreparindent

% Indent first paragraph.
\\usepackage{indentfirst}

\\usepackage{titlesec}
\\usepackage{titling}
\\usepackage{fontspec} % packages for title and section-heading font setting.

% Set Font.
\\setsansfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\\setmainfont{Calibri} % Set serifed font to Calibri. Originally set to 'Times New Roman', but it cannot display certain characters such as ①②③.
\\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}
\\setCJKsansfont{Kaiti TC} % Set Chinese font. NOTE: Remember to append CJK before of the font class. CJK HAS to be there for the font to show.

\\titleformat*{\\section}{\\fontsize{16}{18}\\bfseries\\sffamily}
\\titleformat*{\\subsection}{\\fontsize{14}{16}\\bfseries\\sffamily}
\\titleformat*{\\subsubsection}{\\fontsize{12}{14}\\bfseries\\sffamily} % Set formats for each heading level. 'sffamily' will point to the sans-serif font. In this case, 「楷體」.
\\renewcommand{\\maketitlehooka}{\\sffamily} % Set title font.

% Set quotation font.
\\usepackage{etoolbox}
\\newCJKfontfamily\\quotefont{Kaiti TC}
\\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\\quotefont\\normalsize}

% Tweak default settings.
\\renewcommand{\\baselinestretch}{1.2} % Set line width.
\\renewcommand{\\contentsname}{目次} % Translate content page title to Chinese. (Could possibly be done automatically with '\\usepackage[heading]{CJK}'. TODO experiment. )

% For text-boxes

\\usepackage{mdframed}
\\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\\begin{mdframed}}
\\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\\end{mdframed}}

% [FIXME] ox-latex 的設計不良導致 hypersetup 必須在這裡插入
\\usepackage{hyperref}
\\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, %把紅框框移掉改用字體顏色不同來顯示連結
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  citecolor=[rgb]{0,0.47,0.68},
  filecolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  pagebackref=true,
  linktoc=all,}
"
         ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
         ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
         ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
         ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
         ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
        ))
```

## Sample Org Document:

```org
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

#+BEGIN_QUOTE
㊀㊁㊂ ①②③
#+END_QUOTE

㊀㊁㊂ ①②③
```

## PDF generated:

[image]

---

As apparent from the above example, `Kaiti TC` contains the characters ㊀ etc. but `MingLiU` does not.

How can we define a fallback font for `CJKmainfont` so that ㊀㊁㊂ without the quote can be displayed properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a working solution with the code below:

```latex
\\newCJKfontfamily\\fallbackfont{PingFang TC}
\\newunicodechar{㊀}{{\\fallbackfont ㊀}}
\\newunicodechar{㊁}{{\\fallbackfont ㊁}}
\\newunicodechar{㊂}{{\\fallbackfont ㊂}}
\\newunicodechar{㊃}{{\\fallbackfont ㊃}}
\\newunicodechar{㊄}{{\\fallbackfont ㊄}}
\\newunicodechar{㊅}{{\\fallbackfont ㊅}}
\\newunicodechar{㊆}{{\\fallbackfont ㊆}}
\\newunicodechar{㊇}{{\\fallbackfont ㊇}}
\\newunicodechar{㊈}{{\\fallbackfont ㊈}}
```

I would appreciate other suggestions to the problem, especially with shorter code.